# rotating an image in a canvas in jquery

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I have a canvas and it contains 5 images having different id named as img1, img2, img3, img4 and img5.
Now I am using jquery slider. Now if I change rotation in the slider then the image will be rotated which is assigned for that slider. But in my case, I am able to create multiple sliders but if I make rotation in any one of the sliders, then only the image having id img5 is changing which is not the exact image for that slider. In a short, all sliders are assigning for the last image.
My code is like:

```
$('.slider').slider({
orientation : 'horizontal',
max:180,
min:-180,
value:0,
id:objid,
slide: function(event, ui) {
var $this = $(this);
/* Change the rotation and register that value in data object when it stops */
draggable_elem.css({'-moz-transform':'rotate('+ui.value+'deg)','-webkit-transform':'rotate('+ui.value+'deg)'});
$('.degrees',$this).html(ui.value);
},
stop:function(event, ui) {
newObject.rotation = ui.value;
}
});
```

whereas `objid` is the id of the image.

Please advice, how to distinguish the image for only one slider.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide us with the needed HTML for this (for best help, use JSFiddle or something to explain your problem)?

Comment: Actually, I dont know how to use JSFiddle. Could you help me how to do that?